# Prove that Dual linear program does not have finite optimal solution

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, operations-research

Consider the following

$\displaystyle \max z=x+2y\\s.t.-x+y\le-2\\4x+y\le4\\ x,y\ge0$

Find the dual program and prove graphically that D has no finite optimal solution.

Solution

The dual is given by

$\displaystyle \max -2x+4y\\s.t.-x+4y\ge1\\x+y\ge2\\ x,y\ge0$

In the plot we see that there is no bounded feasible region. And as we have to maximize the objective function $-2x+4y$ then there won't be a fesible solution, because $z$ goes to $\infty$.

[image]

> Is my solution correct? If it is, is it well justified?

Comment: I recall my teacher saying that one would be max and the other min for dual and primal respectively, but in my book says it does not change the max to min, it remains max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph looks ok, but the real trouble is the dual maximizing. Your teacher is right,

> it must be the change from min to max and vice versa in dual problems.

It is though the same reasoning for the minimum in the dual problem as it is possible to move the level set for $z=-2x+4y$ to $-\infty$ within the feasible region.

Comment: Will $z=-2x+4y$ go to $-\infty$ within the fesible region?

Comment: @Alt. You can see it in your graph: the lines $-2x+4y=\text{const}$ (the lines from lower left to upper right corners) may move downwards, i.e. agains the gradient $(-2,4)$ which corresponds to minimizing $z$, as far as one wishes and still staying within the feasible region (far to the right).

Comment: I see, so $y$ goes to $0$ and $x$ to $\infty$, hence $z$ goes to $-\infty $ because $-x$ term

Comment: @Alt. Another good exercise is to set $z=-2x+ay$ and find out for what $a$ that the dual problem does have a solution.

Comment: @Alt. $y$ does not go to $0$ ($x$-axis is not feasible since we need to take the intersection of two regions in the graph). Both $x$ and $y$ go to $+\infty$ along the blue line to the right, but $x$ does it much faster, and $-2x$ dominates in $z$.

Comment: yes yes you're right, I confused the region I though it was the complete quadrant, I can see now that $x$ grows faster because of  it slope

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful answer $A.Γ.$